# .NET Core Google Drive API works on windows but not on linux

Tags: c#, linux, google-drive-api, .net-core

#### Edit4: Bug in MCVE format

`System.AggregateException` in `System.Net.Http.CurlHandler` while using Google Drive API in dotnet core 2.0 in Ubuntu x64 Self Contained Deployment (SCD) without dotnet core runtime or curl installed

Expected Behavior:

Browser opens up with google login page

Exception:

```
    vm@vm-VirtualBox:/media/sf_Projects/test/mcve/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.0/ubuntu-x64/publish$ ./mcve

    Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The type initializer for 'System.Net.Http.CurlHandler' threw an exception.) ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Net.Http.CurlHandler' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Http' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'HttpInitializer' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'System.Net.Http.Native': The specified module or one of its dependencies could not be found.
     (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
       at Interop.Http.GetSslVersionDescription()
       at Interop.HttpInitializer..cctor()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at Interop.Http..cctor()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at Interop.Http.GetSupportedFeatures()
       at System.Net.Http.CurlHandler..cctor()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Net.Http.CurlHandler..ctor()
       at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler..ctor()
       at Google.Apis.Http.HttpClientFactory.CreateSimpleClientHandler()
       at Google.Apis.Http.HttpClientFactory.CreateHandler(CreateHttpClientArgs args)
       at Google.Apis.Http.HttpClientFactory.CreateHttpClient(CreateHttpClientArgs args)
       at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow..ctor(Initializer initializer)
       at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow..ctor(Initializer initializer)
       at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.<AuthorizeAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.<AuthorizeAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
       at mcve.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Work\Projects\test\mcve\Program.cs:line 20
```

#### How to produces the problem?

- Create a dotnet core 2.0 console application.
- copy mcve.csprog

  ```
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
      <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
      <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Google.Apis.Drive.v3" Version="1.35.1.1312" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <None Update="client_secret.json">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </None>
    </ItemGroup>

  </Project>
  ```
- copy Program.cs

  ```
  using System;
  using System.IO;
  using System.Threading;
  using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
  using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
  using Google.Apis.Services;
  using Google.Apis.Util.Store;

  namespace mcve
  {
      class Program
      {

          private static string[] Scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive};


          static void Main(string[] args)
          {

              var stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

              var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                     GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                     Scopes,
                     "user",
                     CancellationToken.None,
                     new FileDataStore("credentials", true)).Result;


              stream.Close();
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- You will require `client_secret.json` which you can download from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=180J2D3F900qngYStIOUe7DjL_MASTlBO)
- copy client_secret.json in the project folder
- compile the program using this command
  `dotnet publish -c Release -f netcoreapp2.0 -r ubuntu-x64`
- now when the binaries are compiled, run it in a fresh install of ubuntu

---

---

---

Repository:

https://github.com/adsau59/DriveSoftwarePublisher

So I am making a software publisher that uses Google Drive, I used dotnet core thinking that it could be ported to linux and mac easily, so after I completed coding and testing or windows, I tried to test it on linux (linuxmint), but it didn't work and I'm getting an exception that I dont understand.

I'm using dotnet core 2.0

Exception Image:

https://s22.postimg.cc/8d0i0pmyp/Screenshot_from_2018-07-26_16-19-13.png

Prototype demo:

https://youtu.be/TdtkTxmOgw8

Binaries:

linux: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gOdqr_TAx3QI1tRsWQe1mdpNOdBq5w54
windows: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BP3ZsUmgri2oYKTOARxzoyS80Qe_rBt3

Edit:

Nuget packages
https://s22.postimg.cc/4ezwpdkmp/image.png

Edit 2:

```
adam@Y50-Linux ~/Desktop/DriveSP_v0.1.0-alpha_ubuntu.16.10-x64 $ ./Publisher init test1

Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The type initializer for 'System.Net.Http.CurlHandler' threw an exception.) ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Net.Http.CurlHandler' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Http' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'HttpInitializer' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'System.Net.Http.Native': The specified module or one of its dependencies could not be found.
 (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at Interop.Http.GetSslVersionDescription()
   at Interop.HttpInitializer..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Interop.Http..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Interop.Http.GetSupportedFeatures()
   at System.Net.Http.CurlHandler..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.CurlHandler..ctor()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler..ctor()
   at Google.Apis.Http.HttpClientFactory.CreateSimpleClientHandler()
   at Google.Apis.Http.HttpClientFactory.CreateHandler(CreateHttpClientArgs args)
   at Google.Apis.Http.HttpClientFactory.CreateHttpClient(CreateHttpClientArgs args)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow..ctor(Initializer initializer)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow..ctor(Initializer initializer)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.<AuthorizeAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.<AuthorizeAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at CommonScripts.Service..ctor(String secretPath, String credentialsJson) in D:\Projects\DriveSoftwarePublisher\CommonScripts\Service.cs:line 50
   at Publisher.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Projects\DriveSoftwarePublisher\Publisher\Program.cs:line 36
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Edit 3:

dotnet outdated

[image: dotnet outdated results]

Comment: What nuget package do you use to access the google drive API?
Is your application has a GUI?

Comment: Seems the problem is in docopt.net package. It says it has only been tested in VS 2012

Comment: Have you checked all the prereqs for .NetCore on Linux?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x

For 2.0 scroll down a good way.

Comment: @cimenx docopt works perfectly, its just that when i create Drive service, the program gets an exception

Comment: Can you edit the question and add what exception is printed @RIPjoker

Comment: @TrevorReid I am not developing it on Linux, I just tested on linux

Comment: @cimenx the nuget packages im using:
https://s22.postimg.cc/4ezwpdkmp/image.png

Comment: Try to run it using dotnet-cli in Linux instead cross building it! I sense something strange here since dotnet core 2.1 replace HTTP implementation using embedded libcurl.

Comment: @cimenx thanks for the suggestion to run it on dotnet cli, here is what i did, as switching between os was very tedious I installed virtual box and install ubuntu (instead of linuxmint) then i installed libicu55 and dotnet-runtime-2.0 then tried running binaries of dotnet runtime instead of the linux and it worked, and guess what when I tried the linix binaries that worked too, so I created a fresh image of ubuntu and tried running the linux binaries, and I got the same error as before

Comment: so what i think is, the environment will have to have dotnet runtime installed to run the app.... How should I make sure the people who want to use my program have dotnet runtime installed?

Comment: As I thought, had you tried using dotnet 2.1?

Comment: To package dotnet runtime with your application, I can only think to package it as snap or appimage. Before that, try to package it as Self-contained deployments (SCD) and see if it's work! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/index#self-contained-deployments-scd

Comment: @cimenx sry for the late reply, I have tried making an SCD but when I run it without dotnet core runtime installed, it gives me the exception i showed you in the post

Comment: @cimenx it turns out when i install curl4 by using, sudo apt install curl, exception doesn't happen, how can I make sure that when someone uses my program they should have curl intalled, like if they have to use my app they curl will be installed automatically

Comment: Since your question is probably bugs in .NET Core 2.0, try to format your question in https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve style❗I will summarize my answer for that with the possible workarounds

Comment: Also, try to install and run dotnet-outdated and share the result in your question &#128521;. Curious if Google.Apis use a deprecated version of some corefx lib.

Comment: @cimenx I did the 'dotnet outdated' and posted its result in the post, I noticed that the api I was using was outdated so I updated it, recompiled and tested it again, without curl installed, I got the same exception

Comment: @cimenx I migrated to dotnet core 2.1 and it worked like a charm, thanks alot for your assist man, I love you... Should I make the question in the format you asked now?

Comment: Yes! Formating it in mcve style can help the others to search and understand this kind of bugs. Glad it helps :)

Comment: @cimenx so should I just copy paste the code in stack-overflow or create a repository for it? and should I create a new post for it, or edit this one?

Comment: Just copy and edit your question will do :)

Comment: @cimenx made the problem mcve format